# It's capturing the mood input value but not the day description value. It only shows up as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to make a form where you type in how your day was(dayDescription) and what your mood(mood) was for the day. Then it's supposed to show the mood as a  title and the dayDescription as a

, however, it shows the dayDescription as [object Object]

//------- JOURNAL ENTRIES ---------

```
    const formEl = document.querySelector("#journal-form");
    const saveEntry = document.querySelector("#save-entry");
    var moodInput = document.querySelector("#mood");
    var textBoxEl = document.querySelector("#day-description");
    var entryDetails = document.querySelector("#entry-details");
    var journal = document.querySelector("#journal");
    var addEntry = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var moodType = moodInput.value;
        var dayDescription = textBoxEl.value;
        if (moodType, dayDescription) {
            moodInput.value = "";
            textBoxEl.value = "";
            var journalEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("journalEntries")) || [];
            var submitEntry = {
                mood: moodType,
                description: textBoxEl
            };
            journalEntries.push(submitEntry);
            localStorage.setItem("journalEntries", JSON.stringify(journalEntries));
            console.log("entries", submitEntry);
        } else {
            alert("Please submit an entry!");
        }
        createEntry();
    }
    function createEntry() {
        // add in journal section
        var journalEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("journalEntries")) || [];
        journal.innerHTML = "";
        console.log("journal entries", journalEntries);
        
        for (let i = 0; i < journalEntries.length; i++) {
            var entryTitle = document.createElement("h2");
            entryTitle.textContent = journalEntries[i].mood;
            journal.appendChild(entryTitle);
            var entryDescription = document.createElement("p");
            entryDescription.textContent = journalEntries[i].description;
            journal.appendChild(entryDescription);
            console.log("Description", entryDescription);
        }
    }
    createEntry();
    saveEntry.addEventListener("click", addEntry);
```

Comment: `description: textBoxEl` Don't you mean `description: dayDescription`?

Comment: You're setting submitEntry.description to textBoxEl, which is your input element. You should be using dayDescription.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thanks, guess I just needed a fresh pair of eyes